# Apache/Passenger - cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I've spun up two different servers to run my rails app using Apache and Passenger but am getting the same error and can't seem to debug the issue.

`cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`

Error:
        Web application could not be started

Error ID:
    e36eb8ab

```
Details:
    cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
      /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:456:in `activate_gem'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:323:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:461:in `running_bundler'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:322:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
      /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'

System information:
    Application root
    /home/ubuntu/sephcordovano
    Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
    development
    Ruby interpreter command
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/ruby
    User and groups
    uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),110(lxd)
    Environment variables
    APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
    SHELL = /bin/bash
    APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
    PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXX4V4Jbk
    USER = ubuntu
    PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
    APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
    PATH = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims:/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
    PWD = /home/ubuntu/sephcordovano
    APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
    LANG = C
    SHLVL = 0
    HOME = /home/ubuntu
    LOGNAME = ubuntu
    SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.1.12
    XDG_DATA_DIRS = /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
    APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
    APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
    IN_PASSENGER = 1
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
    NODE_PATH = /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/nodejs_supportlib
    RAILS_ENV = development
    RACK_ENV = development
    WSGI_ENV = development
    NODE_ENV = development
    PASSENGER_APP_ENV = development
    Ulimits
    Unknown
    System metrics
    ------------- General -------------
    Kernel version    : 4.4.0-1047-aws
    Uptime            : 1h 45m 27s
    Load averages     : 0.08%, 0.02%, 0.10%
    Fork rate         : unknown

    ------------- CPU -------------
    Number of CPUs    :    1
    Average CPU usage :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
      CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
    I/O pressure      :   0%
      CPU 1           :   0%
    Interference from other VMs:   0%
      CPU 1                    :   0%

    ------------- Memory -------------
    RAM total         :    990 MB
    RAM used          :    148 MB (15%)
    RAM free          :    842 MB
    Swap total        :   1023 MB
    Swap used         :      7 MB (1%)
    Swap free         :   1016 MB
    Swap in           : unknown
    Swap out          : unknown

    General Ruby interpreter information
    RUBY_VERSION = 2.4.2
    RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
    RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
    RubyGems version = 2.6.13
    RubyGems paths = ["/home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.4.0", "/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0"]
    Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
    DESTDIR = 
    MAJOR = 2
    MINOR = 4
    TEENY = 2
    PATCHLEVEL = 198
    INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
    EXEEXT = 
    prefix = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2
    ruby_install_name = ruby
    RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
    RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
    exec = exec
    ruby_pc = ruby-2.4.pc
    PACKAGE = ruby
    BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  enc/trans/newline.c
    USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
    MANTYPE = doc
    NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
    vendorarchhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
    sitearchhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
    rubyarchhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    vendorhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/vendor_ruby
    sitehdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/site_ruby
    rubyhdrdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0
    RUBY_SEARCH_PATH = 
    UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
    UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
    configure_args =  '--prefix=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2' 'LDFLAGS=-L/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib ' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include '
    CONFIGURE = configure
    vendorarchdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    vendorlibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0
    vendordir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
    sitearchdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    sitelibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0
    sitedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby
    rubyarchdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    rubylibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0
    ruby_version = 2.4.0
    sitearch = x86_64-linux
    arch = x86_64-linux
    sitearchincludedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/x86_64-linux
    archincludedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/x86_64-linux
    sitearchlibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/x86_64-linux
    archlibdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/x86_64-linux
    libdirname = libdir
    RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2
    RUBY_LIB_VERSION = 
    RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE = 3  /* full */
    RI_BASE_NAME = ri
    ridir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/ri
    rubysitearchprefix = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
    rubyarchprefix = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
    MAKEFILES = Makefile GNUmakefile
    PLATFORM_DIR = 
    THREAD_MODEL = pthread
    SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
    EXPORT_PREFIX = 
    COMMON_HEADERS = 
    COMMON_MACROS = 
    COMMON_LIBS = 
    MAINLIBS = 
    ENABLE_SHARED = no
    DLDLIBS =  -lc
    SOLIBS = 
    LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib -L/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib 
    LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib -L/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib -lruby-static
    LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib -L/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib -lruby-static
    LIBRUBY = libruby-static.a
    LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so
    LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.2.4.2
    LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
    RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
    rubyw_install_name = 
    EXTDLDFLAGS = 
    EXTLDFLAGS = 
    strict_warnflags = -std=gnu99
    warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
    debugflags = -ggdb3
    optflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math
    NULLCMD = :
    DLNOBJ = dln.o
    INSTALL_STATIC_LIBRARY = yes
    EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
    ARCHFILE = 
    LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
    EXTOUT = .ext
    PREP = miniruby
    CROSS_COMPILING = no
    TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
    rubylibprefix = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby
    setup = Setup
    ENCSTATIC = 
    EXTSTATIC = 
    STRIP = strip -S -x
    TRY_LINK = 
    PRELOADENV = LD_PRELOAD
    LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-rpath,%1$-s
    LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
    LINK_SO = 
    ASMEXT = S
    LIBEXT = a
    DLEXT2 = 
    DLEXT = so
    LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
    STATIC = 
    ARCH_FLAG = 
    DLDFLAGS = -L/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib  -Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib
    ALLOCA = 
    codesign = 
    POSTLINK = :
    WERRORFLAG = -Werror
    CHDIR = cd -P
    RMALL = rm -fr
    RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
    RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
    CP = cp
    RM = rm -f
    PKG_CONFIG = 
    PYTHON = 
    DOXYGEN = 
    DOT = 
    MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
    MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
    INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
    INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
    INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
    SET_MAKE = 
    LN_S = ln -s
    NM = nm
    DLLWRAP = 
    WINDRES = 
    OBJCOPY = :
    OBJDUMP = objdump
    ASFLAGS = 
    AS = as
    ARFLAGS = rcD 
    AR = ar
    RANLIB = ranlib
    try_header = 
    CC_VERSION_MESSAGE = gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
    Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
    CC_VERSION = gcc --version
    CSRCFLAG = 
    COUTFLAG = -o 
    OUTFLAG = -o 
    CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
    GNU_LD = yes
    LD = ld
    GCC = yes
    EGREP = /bin/grep -E
    GREP = /bin/grep
    CPP = gcc -E
    CXXFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
    OBJEXT = o
    CPPFLAGS = -I/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include   
    LDFLAGS = -L. -L/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib  -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
    CXX = g++
    CC = gcc
    NACL_LIB_PATH = 
    NACL_SDK_VARIANT = 
    NACL_SDK_ROOT = 
    NACL_TOOLCHAIN = 
    target_os = linux
    target_vendor = pc
    target_cpu = x86_64
    target = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    host_os = linux-gnu
    host_vendor = pc
    host_cpu = x86_64
    host = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    RUBY_VERSION_NAME = ruby-2.4.0
    RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
    RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
    build_os = linux-gnu
    build_vendor = pc
    build_cpu = x86_64
    build = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 2.4.2
    cxxflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
    cppflags = 
    cflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wno-maybe-uninitialized
    target_alias = 
    host_alias = 
    build_alias = 
    LIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
    ECHO_T = 
    ECHO_N = -n
    ECHO_C = 
    DEFS = 
    mandir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/man
    localedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/locale
    libdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib
    psdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/doc/ruby
    pdfdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/doc/ruby
    dvidir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/doc/ruby
    htmldir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/doc/ruby
    infodir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/info
    docdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share/doc/ruby
    oldincludedir = /usr/include
    includedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include
    localstatedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/var
    sharedstatedir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/com
    sysconfdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/etc
    datadir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share
    datarootdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/share
    libexecdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/libexec
    sbindir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/sbin
    bindir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin
    exec_prefix = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2
    PACKAGE_URL = 
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
    PACKAGE_STRING = 
    PACKAGE_VERSION = 
    PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
    PACKAGE_NAME = 
    PATH_SEPARATOR = :
    SHELL = /bin/bash
    UNICODE_VERSION = 9.0.0
    archdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    topdir = /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    Activated Ruby gems
    did_you_mean => 1.1.0
    Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux
    Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
    enumerator.so
    thread.rb
    rational.so
    complex.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/unicode_normalize.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/version.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/platform.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checker.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/delegate.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/formatter.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tmpdir.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.passenger/native_support/5.1.12/ruby-2.4.2-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/io/wait.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/pathname.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/base64.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/shellwords.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
    /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core/version.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails/version.rb
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're pointing Nginx/apache properly inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/app/.rvm/wrappers/default/ruby;
```

Find ruby by running `which ruby`

Comment: Setting `PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby` in apache.conf worked perfectly!

Comment: You just saved my day. I ran into the `cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)` error after upgrading *something* on my Ubuntu server. In my `mod-http-passenger.conf` I replaced the line `passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;` with `passenger_ruby /home/rails/.rbenv/shims/ruby;` which fixed the issue for me. Just run `which ruby` to determine the correct new path.